# hyperledger tls certificate not trusted

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have set up a hyperledger rest server using HTTPS and TLS. I'm wondering why my browser says the connection is not secure though. See images below:

[Connection not secure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujqmp.png)

[Root certificate not trusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhKHr.png)

Do you have to make your own certificates so that they are trusted, or does anyone have any info on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get your certificates from?  If you did not request and obtain them from a trusted CA then this is expected behaviour on a typical Dev environment.  (Perhaps you just used the default certificates from Composer.)

In a production scenario you would request and use certificates that you had obtained (purchased probably) from your organisations usual CA.

This is not a Composer specific problem, but a general HTTP feature.

Comment: Ok - thanks for the clarification @RThatcher. Yeah, I was just using the default certificates from Composer.